# Problem with count (dplyr) within function

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, count, tidyverse

I made a piece of code that I would like to run over different variables

```
#ggplot frequency table
marso <- some_dataset %>%
  count(some_variable)


##ggplot arrange
taart_marso <- marso %>%
  arrange(desc(some_variable)) %>%
  mutate(prop = round(n*100/sum(n), 1),
         lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)
head(taart_marso, 4)

##ggplot piechart
ggplot(taart_marso, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = some_variable)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = n), color = "black", x=1.4)+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  theme_void()
```

I pasted the above within a function and tried to call the function with the same variable and dataset

```
piechart <- function(dataset, variable) {


  mar <- dataset %>%
  count(variable)

taart_mar <- mar %>%
  arrange(desc(variable)) %>%
  mutate(prop = round(n*100/sum(n), 1),
         lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)

ggplot(taart_mar, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = n), color = "black", x=1.4)+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
  theme_void()

}

piechart("some_dataset", "some_variable")
```

If I do this, I receive the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Can anyone help?

Comment: why is `x = ""` in `ggplot`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can make use of `{{}}` if we pass an unquoted argument

```
piechart <- function(dataset, variable) {


   mar <- dataset %>%
              count({{variable}})

   taart_mar <- mar %>%
                  arrange(desc({{variable}})) %>%
                  mutate(prop = round(n*100/sum(n), 1),
                         lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)

   ggplot(taart_mar, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = {{variable}})) +
         geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
        geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = n), color = "black", x=1.4)+
        coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
        theme_void()

   }



piechart(mtcars, vs)
```

[image]

NOTE: the dataset object should not be quoted as it can lead to making use of `get` to extract the values and it can create unnecessary bugs.  Also, the `x = ""` in `aes` is not clear.  So, please make sure to change that part if necessary

---

If we need to pass a quoted string as variable name, convert it to `sym`bol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
piechart <- function(dataset, variable) {

   variable <- rlang::ensym(variable)
   mar <- dataset %>%
              count(!!variable)

   taart_mar <- mar %>%
                  arrange(desc(!!variable)) %>%
                  mutate(prop = round(n*100/sum(n), 1),
                         lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop)
    ggplot(taart_mar, aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = !!variable)) +
       geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
       geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = n), color = "black", x=1.4)+
      coord_polar("y", start = 0)+
      theme_void()

   }



piechart(mtcars, "vs")
```